# Add consecutive count to this ef core query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the below query in Entity Framework Core that reports on amounts of sales, grouped by customer, between given dates.

```
IEnumerable<SalesDataModel> currentSales =
(from s in sales
where s.Date >= [StartDate] && u.Date <= [EndDate]
join c in customers on s.Acct equals c.Account
group s by new { s.Name, c.City } into g
select new SalesDataModel { 
    CustName = g.Key.Name,
    City = g.Key.City,
    MaxBorrowed = g.Max(x => x.Price),
    Average = g.Average(x => x.Price),
    NumDays = 
        g.Sum(x => x.Price > 0 ? 1 : 0),
    ConsecutiveDays = //???
}).ToList();
```

Basically I want to count the number of times within the date span that a given customer made a purchase two days or more in a row. So, start with Day 1, and compare it to Day 2; if Price > 0 for both days, iterate a counter by one. Then check Day 2 against Day 3 with the same criteria, and repeat for as many records as I have for that customer. The counter should not reset to zero if a zero or null Price value is encountered, but it should reset for the next customer.

I found [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899812/linq-to-sql-get-number-of-consecutive-daily-views) asking something similar, but there's got to be an easier way. I'm  using EF Core 5.

Also, full disclosure, this post is a continuation from [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993754/converting-complicated-sql-query-to-entityframework). Since the answer to this question might not be as simple as I hope, a second post seemed the better way.

Comment: Probably you have SQL to count `ConsecutiveDays`? If yes, probably it is Window Functions - not supported by EF any versions.

Comment: Yeah, I see I'm going to have to use FromSqlRaw for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is going to require a FromSqlRaw execution of an SP to make this work.